# Windows 8.1 or 10 for TV display of statistics

Tags: windows-8, kiosk

We want to display real-time business statistics (from a Google Chrome webpage) on big screens at my company's office,  using Windows 8.1 computers connected to plasma screens. These computers are joined to the domain.

We moved these computers in Active Directory to an OU that disables the screensaver + workstation lock.

BUT we're afraid of misuse as the keyboard and mouse is easily accessible (on purpose as we want nearby users to make changes to what is being displayed whenever they feel like it).

Is there a way for the workstation to lock when the mouse/keyboard is moved?
That's the reverse of the typical workstation lock where the workstation is locked where mouse and keyboard is idle for a period of time.